# undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass:

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nested-attributes

Using ruby 2.6 & rails 5.2
And also using rolify gem.

I passed in a nested attribute in my Users edit view for roles to be selectable(editable).But Instead, I am geting

```rb
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
In my edit view.
```

I am using this code snippet in my users edit views

```rb
<%= form_for(@user, url: account_user_path(@user), html: {class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
<%= select_tag "user[role]", options_for_select(@choices, @user.account.roles.first.name), class:'form-control'%>
end
```

I have in my controllers..

#### users_controller

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update,:destroy] 

........
def edit
  set_choices
end

def set_choices
  @choices = []
  @choices << ["Admin", 'admin']
  @choices << ["User", 'user']
end

......
private

def user_params
params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :role)
end
```

### Database

#### RolifyCreateRoles

```rb
class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:roles) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :resource, :polymorphic => true

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table(:users_roles, :id => false) do |t|
      t.references :user
      t.references :role
    end

    add_index(:roles, :name)
    add_index(:roles, [ :name, :resource_type, :resource_id ])
    add_index(:users_roles, [ :user_id, :role_id ])
  end
end
```

Comment: The error says that there is no role associated with that particular user. Check the data in  your database

Comment: @Surya i have edited my question to include the db. Actually, i think i have that association.maybe you could roll throufh it once again please.

Comment: I think it should be @user.roles.first.name because roles belongs to user not account.

Comment: @Saifchaudhry already tried that but it shows same error

Comment: i added a role to a user using the rails console and wrote @user.roles.first.name it worked. But it doesn't For a user without a role, It returns that error stated in the question.(Undefined method `name` for nil:NilClass

Comment: For a user without role you can use @user.roles.try(:first).try(:name)

Answer (score 0):

you can use safe navigation if roles are not present for user then it will handle the case with below code

```
@user&.roles&.first&.name || ''
```

Comment: Though the collection shows to either select Admin or User as role, but  when submited user role is stil Nil.

Comment: try this out @user&.roles&.first&.name || 'user'

Comment: Did that, the matter is, it just output that u have make some execution but it does not make any commit or sql insection.

Comment: Ok, got this work with the rails console $ d=User.find(1)    $  d&.roles&.first&.name || d&.add_role('user')

Comment: glad you got your issue resolved, but as you comment , @user&.roles&.first&.name || 'user' will only print the out put won't add role to the user.

Answer (score 0):

```
@user.present? && @user.has_role?(:admin)
```

This will avoid the error as it check it exist and has the specific role
It solved the problem for me so add it in your policy file and try it

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.